# ¿Por qué no me deja ingresar los datos en los "OUTS" declarados como parámetros de mi funcion sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quiero saber si mi función esta bien, ya que no me deja ingresar a los "outs" , ya que me bota error "," cerca de (into rental_id, ) . Gracias como siempre por sus respuestas.

```
    ERROR: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «,»
      Position: 247
    
        create or replace function mostrar_dato(id in integer,
        out rental_id integer,
        out rental_date timestamp,
        out cliente varchar,
        out empleado varchar)
        language sql
        as
        $$
            select rental_id,rental_date,c.first_name,s.first_name 
            into rental_id ,
            rental_date,
            cliente,
            empleado 

            from rental r inner join 
            customer c on r.customer_id = c.customer_id 
            inner join staff s 
            on r.staff_id = s.staff_id where rental_id = id;
        $$;
        
        select mostrar_dato(27);
```

Comment: Posdata: la impresión de los datos lo hago con "raise notice 'rental id = %, rental date = %, ...' , rental_id, rental_date, ... .

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el mensaje completo de error que te da

Answer (score 0):

Tu función es definida con lenguaje `SQL` por ende va a retornar el resultado de la ultima consulta dentro de la función, bastaría con retirar la clausula `INTO` y debe funcionar:

```
  create or replace function mostrar_dato(id in integer,
        out rental_id integer,
        out rental_date timestamp,
        out cliente varchar,
        out empleado varchar)
        language sql
        as
        $$
            select rental_id,rental_date,c.first_name,s.first_name 
            from rental r inner join 
            customer c on r.customer_id = c.customer_id 
            inner join staff s 
            on r.staff_id = s.staff_id where rental_id = id;
        $$;

select * from mostrar_dato(27);
```